# How to loop through and get individual item stored in Vector

Tags: java, vector

Have a Vector "***data1***" has a values like this...

```
DefaultTableModel model1 = (DefaultTableModel)itemsTableSD.getModel();
Vector data1 = model1.getDataVector();
System.out.println(data1.toString());
```

Result 1:

```
[[row-0-col-0, row-0-col-1, row-0-col-2, row-0-col-3, row-0-col-4, row-0-col-5], [row-1-col-0, row-1-col-1, row-1-col-2, row-1-col-3, row-1-col-4, row-1-col-5]]
```

If loop through the Vector

```
for(int i=0; i<dataMG.size(); i++){
    System.out.println("data1: "+ "Row-" + i + "->" +dataMG.get(i));
    System.out.println("\n");
}
```

I get only rows....

```
data1: Row-0->[row-0-col-0, row-0-col-1, row-0-col-2, row-0-col-3, row-0-col-4, row-0-col-5]

data1: Row-1->[row-1-col-0, row-1-col-1, row-1-col-2, row-1-col-3, row-1-col-4, row-1-col-5]
```

Question:

**How to get the individual item from each row...please**

like...

```
row-0-col-0
row-0-col-1
row-0-col-2

...

row-1-col-3
row-1-col-4
row-1-col-5
```

Please give me directions, thanks

Comment: You need an inner (nested) loop to iterate over each row's items.

Comment: Thanks @Eng.Fouad, I did put inner (nested) loop and achieved it, thank you so much. like **'        for(int i=0; i<dataMG.size(); i++){
         System.out.println("ModelMG: "+ "Row-" + i + "->" +dataMG.get(i));
         System.out.println("\n");
         Vector insideDataMG = (Vector) dataMG.get(i);
         for (int j=0; j<insideDataMG.size(); j++){
          System.out.println("insideModelMG: "+ "Column-" + j + "->" +insideDataMG.get(j));
          System.out.println("\n");
         }
         }'**